# Cant boot ubuntu unless if i have the Ubuntu USB Stick in

Tags: boot, 20.10

I'm using a USB with ubuntu installed on it and it boots up. It allows me to sign in and when I create a file and boot my pc off and boot ubuntu again the folder saves on the PC. Its just that I have to use a USB every single time I have to boot up, I want to change this.

Comment: Can I confirm the situation here? You installed Ubuntu *onto the USB* stick, and now you want to have Ubuntu on the computer's storage? If so, you will need to re-install the OS, choosing the computer's storage device 

Comment: Sounds like you installed the bootloader on the wrong disk. Installing GRUB using the following worked for me: `sudo mount /dev/sdx3 /mnt` 
`sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdx`  Other people swear by Startup Repair.